# Flutter navigator 2.0 force new state to be created

Tags: flutter, state, router, navigator

I'm using the new Pages and Router APIs from Flutter's Navigator 2.0

My issue is that I have pages A and B opened and then a deepLink is called to page A. So what I do is clear the list of `pages` used in the navigator and recreate the pages with a new page A.

But what happens in this moment is that Navigator reuses the same Page A that existed before and only updates its state and properties (of the widget).

I tried overriding the method `canUpdate` on Page (below) in order to tell that page that now it should be rebuild, but the issue is that the Page class is immutable, so it complains that I can't have a non-final variable on it.

```
class CustomPage<T> extends Page<T> {
  final Widget child;
  bool _pageCanBeUpdated = true;

  CustomPage({@required this.child, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => child,
      settings: this,
    );
  }

  void shouldCleanPage() {
    _pageCanBeUpdated = false;
  }

  @override
  bool canUpdate(Page other) {
    return _pageCanBeUpdated && super.canUpdate(other);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it in another way. Instead of overriding the `canUpdate` method, I created a different key for the page.

In my RouterDelegate I keep a "salt" variable as `int _salt` and whenever I need to clean the whole stack of pages, I increment this salt and add append to the key. This way it is different until the next time I have to recreate it all.

0. Salt: `int _salt = 0;`
1. Initially: `[Page(ValueKey('home $_salt')), Page(ValueKey('invites $_salt'))]`
2. Clean pages: `[]`
3. Increment salt: `_salt++`
4. Recreate page with `[Page(ValueKey('home $_salt')`

It forces the recreation of the whole page instead of reusing the ones that already exist.